# Open application properties page from my application

Tags: android, android-activity

If I go to Settings > Apps and tap on application name, it opens such a standard application page (I don't know how to name it properly):

[image: Application properties page]

Could I call this page from my application for a particular application other than mine?

How to do this? I tried to use Activity Launcher to test this out, but firstly didn't find an appropriate activity and secondly I do not understand how to pass parameters there.

Comment: Try [using `ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use an `Intent`?
It should look like this:

```
val uri = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, uri)
if (intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null) {
   startActivity(intent)
}
```

Where `packageName` is a string (e.g. "com.google.android.calendar").

And `startActivity()` is a method of either an `Activity` or `Fragment`.